# Laravel sometimes ignored when using min:

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I'm using a Form Request to validate the update of a Client.

The following line keeps giving me the min:6 error, although there is 'sometimes' before it.

This is an update form, so the user password and password confirm field will be empty, for the update.

```
'users.password' => 'sometimes|confirmed|min:6',
```

So when I don't enter anything in the password (or password_confirm) field I still get the min: error

> The Password must be at least 6 characters.

Comment: Use "nullable" instead of "sometimes" in rules : https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#a-note-on-optional-fields

Comment: Use `'users.password' => 'sometimes|confirmed|min:6|nullable',`

Comment: Thanks guys! That's indeed the answer.

Comment: @Notflip I have posted my answer! Don't forgot to upvote & accept the best answer! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
'users.password' => 'confirmed|min:6|nullable',
```

instead of

```
'users.password' => 'sometimes|confirmed|min:6',
```

Hope this helps you!!

Answer (score 1):

laravel validation "sometimes" will check for rules if the key exists in the request

so "sometimes" will pass the rules if the key is not found in the request

I think your request have "password" => null.

try to remove the key from the request so it will pass it.

check this image:

[image]

Comment: There has no required thing in his case, it's an optionnal field